# Stop panning in react sigma

Tags: reactjs, sigma.js

I am using react sigma for the first time. I can see there is a infinite panning across the grpah. I need to stop that from infinite panning.

I am using @react-sigma/core package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.